# Swift: Optional chaining for optional subscripts

Tags: swift, option-type

I have a `let map : [String: String]` and a `let key: String?`.

What is the most concise way to access `map[key]` (and get back a `String?` if I had a `key` and `None` if I did not)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let value = key.flatMap { map[$0] }
```

would to the trick, using the

```
/// Returns `nil` if `self` is nil, `f(self!)` otherwise.
@warn_unused_result
public func flatMap<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U?) rethrows -> U?
```

method from `struct Optional`.

Alternatively, you can wrap that into a custom subscript method

```
extension Dictionary {
    subscript(optKey : Key?) -> Value? {
        return optKey.flatMap { self[$0] }
    }
}
```

and the simply write

```
let value = map[key]
```

To avoid confusion with the "normal" subscript method, and to make
the intention more clear to the reader of your code, you can define
the subscript method with an external parameter name:

```
extension Dictionary {
    subscript(optional optKey : Key?) -> Value? {
        return optKey.flatMap { self[$0] }
    }
}

let value = map[optional: key]
```

Comment: This answer is getting better and better :-)  What is the scope of the extension? Can I drop it into the class that needs it and it will not have any side-effect on the rest of the project?

Comment: @Thilo: An extension cannot be "inside" a class definition. You can (as far as I know) only use the [access control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) levels, e.g. `private subscript ...` restricts the scope to the defining source file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am going with the decidedly unfancy

```
key == nil ? nil : map[key!]
```

Comment: I'd definitely choose the `flatMap` or `if let` solution over this one anytime

Comment: The thing I don't like about `flatMap` is that it reverses the order of arguments (`map[key]` turns into an operation on the key). But hiding this behind an extension like in @MartinR's answer is neat.